# How to fetch data from firebase realtime database in intervals. Or fetch and show data as live data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new at programming and I started using Ionic Framework for building apps as experience. I'm currently learning to build a basic social media app where anonymous users post on the platform.

I'm now at the stage where users can comment on a post. However, I have trouble showing on the view the live number of comments per post.

The way I count comments is to fetch the post data from firebase, count the number of comments and then show to the view.

I have tried using an interval to fetch the post data per x number of seconds to refresh the post data. It kinda works, but the problem is the ion-content(view) keeps reloading like the screen keeps blinking every time the data is refreshed/reloaded. And after a while when running on google chrome dev tools, it crashes and says 'Out of resources'

Is there a better way I can show live data from a firebase realtime database? an example would be greatly appreciated.

home.page.ts

```
import { PostsService } from '../posts/posts.service';
import { Posts } from '../posts/posts.model';


export class HomePage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  listedLoadedPosts: Posts[];
  private postSub: Subscription;
  commentCount: string[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private postService: PostsService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postSub = this.postService.posts.subscribe(posts => {
      this.listedLoadedPosts = posts; 

      const source = interval(10000);
      this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => 
      this.constantlyFetchCommentCount());
    });

  }


constantlyFetchCommentCount(){
  this.commentCount = [];
  this.postService.fetchPosts().subscribe(() => {

    // used to count comments in each posts and pushes it to commentCount[]. 
    for (const item of this.listedLoadedPosts) {
      this.commentCount.push((Object.values(item.comments).length - 1).toString());
    }

  });

}

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.commentCount = [];
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.postService.fetchPosts().subscribe(() => {

      // used to count comments in each posts and pushes it to commentCount[].
      for(const item of this.listedLoadedPosts){
        this.commentCount.push((Object.values(item.comments).length - 1).toString());
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    });

  }

}
```

View / html

```
// placed inside ion-virtual-scroll and ion-list
<ion-label >{{commentCount[i]}}</ion-label>
```

posts.service.ts

```
interface PostsData {
 comments: object;
 // also other data;
}

interface Comments {
  comment: string;
}


export class PostsService {
  private Pposts = new BehaviorSubject<Posts[]>([]);
  private Ccomments = new BehaviorSubject<Comment[]>([]);

  get posts() {
    return this.Pposts.asObservable();
  }

  get comments() {
    return this.Ccomments.asObservable();
  }


 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 



  fetchPosts() {
    return this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: PostsData }>(
        'https://whatever.firebaseio.com/whatever.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(resData => {
          const posts = [];
          for (const key in resData) {
            if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              posts.push(
                new Posts(
                  key,
                  resData[key].message,
                  // resData[key].description,
                  // etc....
                  // etc..
                   resData[key].comments
                )
              );
            }

          }
          return posts.reverse(); 
        }),
        tap(posts => {
          this.Pposts.next(posts);
        })
      );
  }






  fetchComments(id) {
    return this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: Comments }>(
        `https://whatever.firebaseio.com/whatever/${id}/comments.json`
      )
      .pipe(
        map(resData => {
          const comment = [];
          for (const key in resData) {
            if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              comment.push(
                new Comment(
                  key,
                  resData[key].comment
                )
              );
            }

          }
          return comment;
        }),
        tap(comment => {
          this.Ccomments.next(comment);
        })
      );
  }


}
```

posts.model.ts

```
export class Posts {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public message: string,
    // etc.... 
    public comments: object
  ) {}
}


export class Comment {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public comment: string
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: why are you calling json file? If you were to actually use firebase **realtime database**, it would be realtime out of the box, hence the name ;)

Comment: I'm new to web programming, some of these code, I got out of tuturials from udemy where he also used firebase realtime database. Is there a link I can check out 'realtime out of the box'.

Comment: check this one out. You are not using firebase "as you should" ;) https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/build-group-chat-with-firestore/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides some really cool helper functions for exactly this behaviour. Check out how to set it up here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

That will give you access to stuff like this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

In particular, the `on` function allows realtime data.

You might also want to take a look at AngularFire, a great library for using Firebase with Angular:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192).